# Open Storage permission dialog from service

Tags: java, android

I want to show storage permission dialog in android, But i don't have any activity instance. I have keyboard service context. So how to open permisson dialog without activity?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to as the "storage permission dialog"? Do you mean [`createAccessIntent()` on `StorageVolume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String))?

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE dialog for storage permisson

Comment: You cannot ask for a runtime permission except from an activity. For a custom input method editor, my guess is that you should do this from [its settings activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method#DefiningIME).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `You can show AlertDialogs from Activity only`.

Why don't you make an activity without view. and ask permission in oncreate.

Answer (score -1):

Service actually inherits from context, so you don't need an activity.

```
MyService extends Service { 


  public void myMethod() {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("title")
      .setMessage("message")
      .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
      .show();
  }
}
```